# Bypass file system max file name length

Tags: linux, filesystems, filenames

How to bypass file system max file name length? Is there a filesystem, which supports arbitrary length file names? It seems that pretty much all filesystems limit file names length to ~255 characters.

Comment: Please make sure there is no [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378/355310) here. What do you need long names for?

Answer (score 1):

Wikipedia has a [list](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_file_systems#Limits) of filesystems together with the maximum name length. All of the typical Linux filesystems do have a limit.

And even if you'd write a filesystem yourself with no name length limit (which is easily possible in Linux), you'd still run into issues with programs using the POSIX constants as limits. So unless you choose the programs you want to use to operate on this filesystem carefully (or patch existing misbehaving programs), you are still stuck. See [here](https://eklitzke.org/path-max-is-tricky) for a discussion on `PATH_MAX` and `NAME_MAX` and their (mis-)usage.